# Navigation using Marmalade

Tags: c++, android, marmalade

How do I achieve navigation to different views in Marmalade? Like what using `startActivity(intent)` in Android does.
I know that there's only a single view in Marmalade, but still couldn't figure out how to make a similar example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to know that there's nothing similar like `Activities` in `Marmalade`. Because Marmalade works on Game loop, in which a particular rendering has to be done frequently in the loop, so as to make it look persistent on the screen. Something like what we do in the custom View's `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method, although we use `invalidate()` method to do that instead of the loop.
The `CIwMaterial` looks similar like a fullScreen View which can be used in lace of the `Activity`, though there's nothing like the same in it. `IwGxSetMaterial()` is the global function to render the newer material on the screen.
This answer is not perfect, but atleast will help those who want to code in `C++` using `marmalade` for the first time and previously doing it using the `Android SDK`.
**PS:** Kindly correct me wherever I am wrong.